# Measure sub time into a method

Tags: performance, statistics, postsharp, stopwatch

I am using PostSharp to log performance and other statistics on some methods. I was asked to measure the performance and time taken on some sub tasks, such as calling an external web service, or a large database, etc.

For example, I have a method with the AoPLoggingAttribute applied. AoPLoggingAttribute inherits from OnMethodBoundaryAspect, so it supports all know methods (OnEntry, OnExit, OnSuccess, etc)

```
    [AoPLogging]
    public MyClass[] MyMainMethod(string myid)
    {
        //Some code here
        LongExecutingTask();
        //Rest of the code here
    }
```

What is the best approach to measure the time taken by LongExecutingTask ? I don't care if it's part of the total executing time, but somehow I need to know the time taken from this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use postsharp you could make a timer aspect like this

```
public class TimingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect   
{     
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        timer.Reset();
        timer.Start();

        base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Execution took {0} milli-seconds", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

Now just attach the aspect to the method you want to time

```
[Timing]
public void LongExecutingTask() {}
```

Remember that postsharp, or AOP in general, works by attaching to the method being called. Not by adding code insert your main method (or whereever you are calling the methods)

**Update**: If you really want to keep track of the whole callstack you could do something like this

```
public class TimingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect   
{     
    static List<Stopwatch> callstack = new List<Stopwatch>();
    static int callstackDepth = 0;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        callstack.Add(timer);

        ++callstackDepth;

        base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        --callstackDepth;

        var timer = callstack[callstackDepth];
        timer.Stop();

        if (callstackDepth == 0) {
           //Add code to print out all the results
           Console.WriteLine("Execution took {0} milli-seconds", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

           callstack.Clear();
        }

        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

Now this only works with 1 single callstack. If you were to have 2 LongExecutingTasks in your main method you would have to think about how you want to report over thoes. But maybe this gives you an idea how you could keep track of the whole callstack.

Comment: Thanx for the answer Batavia. This is what I am doing right now, however I need to measure the time taken by a sub task, in this example the  LongExecutingTask(). With the method you described, I am measuring the total time taken by the parent method (in this case the MyMainMethod)

Comment: Actually if you pay attention to the last part of my code snippet you see i add the timing attribute to the LongExecutingTask method. In that case it will measure that method, not the MyMainMethod

Comment: Yes Batavia, I noticed that, but I need to measure both times, from MyMainMethod and LongExecutingTask. Let's say I apply the Timing attr on both. How I will add up the two timings on one log event?

Comment: who does it has to be 1 log event?wouldn't 2 log lines (1 for each) be just as good?

Comment: I did add some sample code that you could take as a starting point for keeping track of both of them at the same time.

Comment: That worked. I even managed to have a check if the calling method is in the namespace MyCompany.MySolution.MyDBClass, so I log this timer separately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must assign your timer to the MethodExecutionArgs in order to get accurate results in a multi-threaded environment. PostSharp internally assigns to a static class, so any members risk being overwritten by concurrent invocations.

```
public class TimingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.MethodExecutionTag = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var sw = (Stopwatch)args.MethodExecutionTag;
        sw.Stop();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} executed in {1} seconds", args.Method.Name,
                                           sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    }
}
```